# Randomize answers in examdesign documentclass?

Tags: random-numbers, examdesign

I am using the `examdesign` documentclass to write multiple versions of a multiple choice test. The package is great at randomizing question ordering, but I would like to randomize answer order as well. I've read the documentation and haven't found anything. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: [exams](http://ctan.org/pkg/exams) can do this, if I understand what you want. My interpretation differs from that of the person who provided the existing answer to this question, however.

Comment: Thanks, @cfr. exams seems to have not great documentation, though. Are you aware of a minimum working example?

Comment: The documentation is fine, as far as I remember. You just can't read it on CTAN because you need to generate it from the `.dtx` in the usual way. If you download it, you can typeset the documentation and see if you think the package might do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If using another package is acceptable for you, you should consider `automultiplechoice`, which also provides free software (for linux or osx) to correct the completed answer sheet scans for you. See http://home.gna.org/auto-qcm/

Comment: Here the link seems to be dead. I've found another download for `automultiplechoice` here: https://download.auto-multiple-choice.net/