# Randomizing the order of multiplechoices in examdesign class

Tags: examdesign

Is there a way to randomize the order of multiple choice in examdesign class? Unfortunately the NumberOfVersions does not work like that.

Here is an example of multiple choices.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{examdesign}
\usepackage[hmargin=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\class{Mathematics}
\def\namedata{Name: \hrulefill}
%\NoKey
%\NumberOfVersions{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{multiplechoice}
\begin{question}
    Something?
    \choice{Yes}
    \choice{No}
    \choice[!]{Maybe}
    \end{question}
\end{multiplechoice}%

\end{document}
```

I am looking for something similar to the package `exam-randomizechoices` in order to use `\setrandomizerseed{n}` for any number n, however it only works in exam-class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Randomize answers in examdesign documentclass?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289751/randomize-answers-in-examdesign-documentclass)

Comment: @anastygnome I tried. In Overleaf, it says "LaTeX Error: File `automultiplechoice.sty' not found.

Comment: @cabohah The esami package as the first answer suggested does not work in examdesign class.

Comment: @UnknownW The question has more than one answer. AFAIK `automultiplechoice` is not available at Overleaf. You should use a local installation.

Comment: @cabohah I've just installed TeXstudio. The package "automultiplechoice" does not even exist in MikTeX Console ...

Comment: "Local installation" does not only mean a local TeX distribution but also a local installation of `automultiplechoice`. See the links in my comments to the corresponding answers to the linked questions. There are all files you need to download and install and a manual for it.

Comment: @cabohah Ah, I see. That's new to me. I just realized that this package is designed for Linux. There is also a list, which works, but Windows is not one of them (https://www.auto-multiple-choice.net/download.en). Unfortunately I have no knowledge of Linux or all other ...

Comment: It's a perl script. Perl is also available for Windows. So at least the portable version should also run with Windows. But I cannot test it, I'm not a Windows user.